# GitHub - Waiting for a runner to pick up this job

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to commit to GitHub.
Before this, GitHub is able to pick up the runner when committed.

Unfortunately, a few days ago, it keeps waiting for a runner to pick up the job.
I'm using self-hosted to run it. May I know what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow the page "[**Checking the status of a self-hosted runner**](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-self-hosted-runners)" and see if said runner is still online.

> In your organization or repository, navigate to the main page and click  Settings.
>
> In the left sidebar, click `Actions`, then click `Runners`.
>
> Under "Runners", you can view a list of registered runners, including the runner's name, labels, and status.
>
> The status can be one of the following:
>
> - Idle: The runner is connected to GitHub and is ready to execute jobs.
> - Active: The runner is currently executing a job.
> - Offline: The runner is not connected to GitHub. This could be because the machine is offline, the self-hosted runner application is not running on the machine, or the self-hosted runner application cannot communicate with GitHub.

From there, you can check network connectivity, TLS certificate and log files.

> Log files are kept in the `_diag` directory where you installed the runner application, and a new log is generated each time the application is started. >
> The filename begins with `Runner_`, and is followed by a UTC timestamp of when the application was started.

Reviewing the latest logs should give you some clues as to the current state of your runner.

---

As mentioned by the OP, checking the status of the runner service is the first step before [restarting it](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/configuring-the-self-hosted-runner-application-as-a-service#starting-the-service).
The documentation mentions [Linux services](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-self-hosted-runners#using-journalctl-to-check-the-self-hosted-runner-application-service), but on Windows, from a PowerShell session:

```
get-service -name "actions.runner._services.runnername"
start-service -name "actions.runner._services.runnername"
```

See [`actions/runner` issue 717](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/717) as an example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since I'm not the owner of the repository, I checked the status in Services app and the runner is working

Comment: @damia perfect, well done. The page I mention does include restarting the service indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to re-run the GitHub runner in the following way (If you're not the owner of the GitHub organization or repository):

1. Open the services app: Windows key + R
2. Type: services.msc, Enter
3. Look for the GitHub Runner service and check the status.
4. If the status is 'Stop', click 'Start' [make sure that all the queued request is canceled before click 'Start']
5. You can ask the GitHub owner to double-check the status in the GitHub setting and try to re-run all jobs.

P/S: if you encounter with logon error, you need to ensure that the password is correct in Log On tab